# What's the font used in the 1st edition of the book series New Practical Chinese Reader?

Tags: fonts, books

## Table of contents

- The context
- The problem
- What I've tried

## The context

The book series ["新实用汉语课本" (New Practical Chinese Reader)](https://www.blcup.com/EnSeriesBook/index/1568) has 6 volumes and some of those volumes have 1, 2 or 3 editions.

I'm currently enrolled in a course and we are using the 1st edition of that book series.  I want to install the same font that is used in that book in order to get more familiar with that style of writing.

I'm aware of [variant Chinese characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Chinese_characters). I could identify that some characters have variations while others not. These are some characters that vary according to

Character 汉 (in general terms, all characters that have the component 氵, also called 三点水)

[image]

Character 这 (in general terms, all characters that have the 辶 component)

[image]

Character 荒

[image]

## The problem

I don't know the exact name of the font that the authors used for typing the book and I don't find official information on this topic, so I guess I'll have to look a similar font and the best scenario is that I found the exact same font that the authors used.

Below, you can find screenshots of the characters with variants, which I showed in the first section, that appear in the book. Just to make it clear, I want to find a font that show the characters as similar as shown in the screenshots.

Character 汉 (photo from New Practical Chinese Reader vol. 1 ed. 1 p. 38)

[image]

Character 这 (photo from New Practical Chinese Reader vol. 1 ed. 1 p. 49)

[image]

Character 荒 (photo from New Practical Chinese Reader vol. 6 ed. 1 p. 178)

[image]

Now, I will paste some screenshots of texts from the book just in case it helps you find the exact font.

New Practical Chinese Reader vol. 1 ed. 1 page 198

[image]

New Practical Chinese Reader vol. 2 ed. 1 page 258

[image]

New Practical Chinese Reader vol. 6 ed. 1 page 202

[image]

If you think I should delete these pictures due to copyright violations, let me know and I will delete them or you can also delete them.

## What I've tried

I tried looking up information about the font that is used in the book in the official website of the publisher of this book series using advanced Google search (see code block below),  but didn't find anything relevant. I also tried to read the first pages of the book hoping this information was mentioned there, but wasn't able to find it.

```
site:blcup.com ("新实用汉语课本" OR "New Practical Chinese Reader") ("font" OR "字体)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To those with an eye for Chinese typefaces and calligraphy, the computer typeface you are referencing is one from the 楷體 / 楷体 *kǎitǐ* "[regular script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)", adapted for 'zh-cn' Chinese (Simplified) printing.

Of the font families in your image then, the one labelled *FandolKai* will be closest; however, as you point out, the last 点 of the 三点水 in 汉 is the "short" variant in FandolKai whereas in the 新实用汉语课本 it's the "long variant".

Looking at *MS KaiTi* and *ST KaiTi* (the 楷体 fonts that come in my version of Microsoft Word): *ST KaiTi* has the "long"-ish variant where the last 点 comes up to above the end of the second 点 in 汉, and approaches the left of the 几 in 没. This agrees with the images above.

Thus, it is very likely to be either one of those, *or* a house variant thereof.